# AStar in 3D for isometric game

Tags: ios, path-finding, a-star, 2d-games, isometric

We're developing an isometric game that so far has had a single ground level (y = 0) for the avatar to walk on. Pathfinding for this can be solved with a relatively simple 2D AStar tile map.

We're now looking to add objects in the world that can elevate the avatar, thus creating a problem of pathfinding in 3D space. These objects are distributed sparsely in the room, so I want to avoid keeping an entire 3D map of the room for a 3D AStar implementation. I've attached screenshots to illustrate.

[image: The avatar should be able to walk on top of the tables]

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: This question might better be asked over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com (by the way: I love the graphics, I'm a big fan of isometric games! :-))

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I've moved the post there.